# Unable to get Gnu C Library debug symbols

Tags: c, debug

I have two machines. One is Intel x86_64, the other is aarch64 (although I doubt the architecture variation is the problem). Both are Ubuntu. I compile the same program on each of the machines, with the same make and make defs file:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS = -fopenmp -O3 -g
LDFLAGS = -fopenmp  -L$(OMP_TR4_DIR) -lomp -Wl,-rpath=$(OMP_TR4_DIR) -O3 -g
CPP = /usr/bin/cpp
LIBS =
```

On the x86 machine, I see all the debug symbols. On the aarch machine, I see only the
I have installed the libc and OpenMP debug symbols in the same manner on both machines
(which included geting the debug symbol packages as explained here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages).

The same happens with clang/llvm, not just the gnu compiler.

Why could this happen? Is there some environment variable that might not be set on the aarch machine?